# why is oracle sequence jumping by 2 when it is set to increment by 1?

Tags: php, sql, oracle, symfony, oracle11g

so this is perplexing me.. so I got this syntax in my JPA code: (which I follow instructions and the syntax is correct)

```
 @SequenceGenerator(name="oracle_gen", sequenceName="TEST_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="oracle_gen")
```

where I got a sequence in my Oracle 10 named "TEST_SEQ" which is set to increment by 1

It works now.. but when it inserts my row, the ID column (where the sequence is set to) increase by 2.. like 17, 19, 21, etc..

When I did select test_seq.nextval from dual from oracle, it currently say 22 but I know if I add another row from my java application, it'll be 23.. I can't figure out why and where it is adding another 1. The sequence is already set to NOCACHE (in Oracle).. what am I doing wrong? Help! :(

Ok.. this is so odd.. I just realized whenever I do a select test_seq.nextval, it keep increasing my value?! I do have a trigger on the database. Is that what's causing it? sorry, I'm new to Oracle/pl/sql.

thanks for any help.

Comment: What does the trigger do? Please update your question to the trigger code. Also, are there any functions being used when inserting/updating the data that might also contain a sequence call?

Answer (score 2):

You're possibly misusing `NEXTVAL`. From [Using Sequences](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/views002.htm#i1007824) (emphasis mine):

> A sequence is referenced in SQL statements with the `NEXTVAL` and `CURRVAL` pseudocolumns; each **new sequence number** is generated by a reference to the sequence **pseudocolumn `NEXTVAL`**, while the **current sequence number** can be **repeatedly referenced** using the **pseudo-column `CURRVAL`**.

Answer (score 2):

Either the issue is with your RDBMS or with your application code. The former can be checked easily.

1. CREATE SEQUENCE ;
2. Use a "SELECT .CURRVAL, .NEXTVAL FROM DUAL;" statement to check if it is really incrementing by 2. If it increments by 1 then your RDBMS is fine and the issue is with your application code. The sequence is getting fired at some place where it is either not intended or you are unaware of.

To check on the application side, you will need to check all the places in your application where you have used this sequence. This can also be checked easily using DBA_SOURCE view which has the same columns as ALL_SOURCE view. Check this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_2055.htm#i1588578).

Good Luck